# Баг в методе toFixed?

Tags: javascript

```js
let num = 1.123456789; 
alert(+num.toFixed(4)); // Должен выводить 1.1234, но выводит 1.1235.
                        // Почему? Куда подевалась 4?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let num = 1.123456789;
console.log(+num.toFixed(4)); // Должен выводить 1.1234, но выводит 1.1235.
// по правилам округление 5 производится в большую сторону

let num2 = Math.floor(num * 10000) / 10000;
//использовали округление в меньшую
console.log(num2.toFixed(4));
```

Comment: toFixed всегда увеличивает последнее число на +1?

Answer (score 2):

`.toFixed` округляет число, всё в порядке, так и должно быть

Читать [Возвращаемое значение](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed), второе предложение

Воспользуйся этим:

```js
const toFihed=(n, cut=2)=>((parseInt(n*Math.pow(10, cut)))/Math.pow(10, cut));
console.log(toFihed(313.239935, 3));
```

Comment: А как сделать, чтобы результат был 1.1234, а не 1.1235?

Comment: @Black_Viper я как раз писал..)